# Builds fail: https://apt.puppetlabs.com, certificate chain uses expired certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, puppet, apt

My builds started failing this afternoon, with this:

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/Server_init::Apt_get_update/Exec[apt-get-update]/returns:
Err:16 https://apt.puppetlabs.com bionic Release

Notice: /Stage[main]/Server_init::Apt_get_update/Exec[apt-get-update]/returns: 
Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. 
The certificate chain uses expired certificate.  Could not handshake: 
Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 13.33.171.122 443]
```

I assume the expired certificate expired this morning, since an earlier successful build.

How do I sort out which cert it is which has failed?  And what I can do to get it updated.  This says it is some cert in the chain, which I assume means that it is not necessarily the one for apt.puppetlabs.com.

Is there some way for me to tell apt to ignore the certs on this repo, for the time being, so I can resume work on my ticket, instead of this new bug?

Answer (score 2):

There may be a more convenient way to do this, but here is how I found the broken link in the certificate chain:

```
openssl s_client </dev/null -showcerts -connect apt.puppetlabs.com:443 -servername apt.puppetlabs.com | awk 'BEGIN { pem_to_text = "openssl x509 -noout -text" }; /BEGIN CERTIFICATE/ { on = 1 }; on == 1 { print $0 | pem_to_text }; /END CERTIFICATE/ { on = 0; close(pem_to_text) }'
```

At the time of writing, one of the certificates in the chain (`CN = USERTrust RSA Certification Authority`) had expired as of May 30 10:48:38 2020 GMT.

Note, however, that on newer operating system versions (like Ubuntu 20.04) the problem does not cause an error, because the `ca-certificates` package contains an updated CA certificate for the same entity and public key, that is valid through Jan 18 23:59:59 2038 GMT, and newer versions of libssl (OpenSSL) take advantage of that fact (it seems) to verify the leaf certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue, with the same error from apt, however my certificates are valid for any other tool (curl, get, browsers). Checked the whole chain of certificates - and they are valid.

Comment: please consider putting this into a comment on the question as this doesnt answer the question